# Is there a standard definition for __cplusplus in c++14?

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm looking to setup some preprocessor stuff, and I'd like a more exact number for what `__cplusplus` in C++14 should be defined as. Is there one mandated by the standard?

Comment: N3936 says `201402L`. N3797 still says C++11's.

Comment: Tha's the point with drafts; predicting the future is hard. C++98 ended up with a 1997 value.

Comment: clang++ 3.5.0 already has the right definition, g++ 4.9.0 does not: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/423c4f858358d017

Comment: I just use `#if __cplusplus > 201103L`

Comment: @BryanChen I'd like to avoid that, as there will inevitably be more c++ standards (c++1z).

Comment: If you want to check for specific language features instead of a language version, maybe you'll like to follow [this proposal](http://isocpp.org/std/standing-documents/sd-6-sg10-feature-test-recommendations).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, this was an extremely useful answer. It appears that the GNU compiler has implemented these definitions, and I will be using them to test for specific features.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

N3936<sup>*</sup> §16.8 [cpp.predefined]/p1:

> 1 The following macro names shall be defined by the implementation:
>
> `__cplusplus`
>
> The name `__cplusplus` is defined to the value `201402L` when
>   compiling a C++ translation unit.

N3936 is the final working draft that became C++14, and the number `201402L` is consistent with the meeting at which the C++14 standard is sent out for final balloting ([February 2014](http://isocpp.org/blog/2014/02/trip-report)).

<sub><sup>*</sup>Those interested in obtaining a copy of the C++ standard should check out [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents)</sub>

Answer (score 63):

cppreference has information on the standard values of the `__cplusplus` macro in the section "[Predefined macros](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#Predefined_macros)." Currently the standard values are:

`199711L` (C++98 or C++03)
`201103L` (C++11)
**`201402L` (C++14)**
`201703L` (C++17)
`202002L` (C++20)

The macro's value for any given version isn't firmly established until the final standard is published. Therefore, as of June 2019, there was no way to know what the macro value for C++2a would be (and as of Feb 2021 there's no way to know what the value will be for C++2b).

Library vendors typically gate their "C++2a" features on `#if __cplusplus > 201703L`, and their "C++2b" features on `__cplusplus > 202002L`, and so on.

Compiler vendors with a "C++2a" mode simply picked any arbitrary value for `__cplusplus` that made the library vendors' checks happy:

GCC (8.x thru 10.x) `-std=c++2a` mode uses `__cplusplus == 201709L`.
Clang (5.x thru 9.x) `-std=c++2a` mode uses `__cplusplus == 201707L`.
Microsoft Visual Studio (19.20 thru 19.28) `/std:c++latest` mode uses `__cplusplus == 201705L` [if and only if you pass `/Zc:__cplusplus`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-now-correctly-reports-__cplusplus/)! Otherwise it uses `199711L`. So watch out for that!

How have transitions historically been handled?:

Clang 4.0.1 `-std=c++1z` set `__cplusplus == 201406L`. Clang 5.0.0 introduced `-std=c++17` and `-std=c++2a`, made `-std=c++1z` a synonym for `-std=c++17`, and bumped the macro (no matter which of `17`/`1z` you used) to the standard value `201703L`. Clang 10.0 introduced `-std=c++20`, made `-std=c++2a` a synonym for `-std=c++20`, and bumped the macro to the standard value `202002L`. As of Feb 2021, Clang has no formal "C++2b" mode.

GCC 5.1 introduced `-std=c++1z` and `-std=c++17` as synonyms out of the gate, setting `__cplusplus == 201500L`. GCC 7.1 bumped the value (no matter which spelling you used) to the standard value of `201703L`. GCC 8.1 introduced `-std=c++2a` with `__cplusplus == 201709L`. GCC 10.1 introduced `-std=c++20` as a synonym for `-std=c++2a` (but left the macro at `201709L`). As of Feb 2021, GCC trunk has introduced `-std=c++2b` with `__cplusplus == 202100L`.

Oddly, according to Godbolt Compiler Explorer, MSVC bumped the macro for `-std:c++latest` mode from `201704L` to `201705L` sometime between MSVC 19.16 and 19.20. As of Feb 2021, as far as I know, MSVC has no formal "C++20" mode.

Comment: For reference, it's now standardised as `202002L` for C++20 (GCC 10.2.0 with `--std=c++20` reports `201709L` though, while Clang 11.0.1 goes with `202002L` already).

Comment: FYI, Clang 12 (in release candidate as of Mar 3, 2021) introduced `-std=c++2b` with `__cplusplus == 202101L`.

Comment: Just tested on gcc 12.2, and `g++ --std=c++23` defines `__cplusplus` as `202100L`