# Detect supported C++ standards with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a small cmake-based C++11 library that could be improved by using some C++14 and some C++17 features.

To that end I want CMake to test whether `cxx_std_14` and/or `cxx_std_17`is in the list [CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FEATURES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html), as hinted at in the related SO question [How to detect C++11 support of a compiler with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984442/how-to-detect-c11-support-of-a-compiler-with-cmake/20165220#20165220).

I can't quite figure out how to write this test, though. What I *think* should work, doesn't:

```
list (FIND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FEATURES} "cxx_std_14" _index)
if (${_index} GREATER -1)
   message("YAY 14")
else()
   message("NAY 14")
endif()

# -> CMake Error .... (list):
#      list sub-command FIND requires three arguments
```

(Because the mimumum CMake version is 2.8.7 I have to use [list(FIND ...)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:list) instead of the newer, more concise [IN_LIST](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html)).

`CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FEATURES` seems to be a semicolon-separated string, so this ugly snippet works:

```
if ("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FEATURES}" MATCHES "cxx_std_14")
    message("YAY 14")
else()
    message("NAY 14")
endif()
```

Surely, this isn't the proper way to do it... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If it's a _library_, don't you want to cater to the target system's compiler rather than the library build system's compiler? e.g.  why do this with CMake rather than with `#ifdef if __cplusplus > 201402L` and such?

Comment: `list` commands accept the **list name**, not its *content*. Correct usage is: `list(FIND CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FEATURES "cxx_str_14" _index)`.

Comment: @einpoklum As far as I understand, `__cplusplus` is not a sure thing (across platforms and compilers) for detecting C++14 or C++17.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Aah... Yes indeed.

Comment: @mcmayer: You are mistaken... this macro [is an official part of the standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26089319/1593077); if the compiler doesn't provide it, that means it doesn't reliably support the standard. Infinitely many libraries (probably including the standard libraries) rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's a good or bad way, but I do it by enumerating the possible compilers I support:

```
set(CompilerName_tmp "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}")
string(TOLOWER "${CompilerName_tmp}" CompilerName_tmp)
set(CompilerVersion_tmp "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION}")
if(LINUX)
    if("${CompilerName_tmp}" STREQUAL "gnu")
        set(CompilerName_tmp "gcc")
        endif()
        if("${CompilerVersion_tmp}" VERSION_LESS "4.8.1")
            set(Cxx11Available FALSE CACHE INTERNAL "")
        else()
            set(Cxx11Available TRUE CACHE INTERNAL "")
        endif()
    else()
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Unexpected compiler: ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")
    endif()
elseif(WINDOWS)
    if("${CompilerName_tmp}" STREQUAL "intel")
        if("${CompilerVersion_tmp}" VERSION_LESS "15.0.0")
            set(Cxx11Available FALSE CACHE INTERNAL "")
        else()
            set(Cxx11Available TRUE CACHE INTERNAL "")
        endif()
    else()
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Unexpected compiler: ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")
    endif()
endif()
```

Another possibility is to put all the C++11 features you use in a single example, and try to compile it with `try_compile` during the configuration.