# In MSVC 16.10.1, Intellisense and compiler disagree about __cplusplus ('201705' vs. '202004')

Tags: visual-c++, intellisense

In MS Visual Studio 2019, Ver. 16.10.1 (or 16.11.0 Preview 1.0), Toolset v142
with Option `/std:latest /Zc:__cplusplus`

Intellisense tells me __cplusplus is ' 201705L',
but the compiled program prints the following:
"MSVC= '1929', __plusplus = '202004'":

[image]

Can someone please confirm that this is an error and tell me where and how I should/could best report something like this?

(
With the MS compiler currently available at Godbolt.org, this discrepancy does not occur. The compilation there says '201705', see https://godbolt.org/z/oax35erME.
)

Comment: 1. The "Help/Report Issue" or similar might be the best place to report. 2. [Here is more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56483887/1270789).

Comment: Maybe they have added "c++20" switch and updated "c++ latest" to be the next after c++20 instead of being the next after c++17?

Comment: As for "compiler vs intellisence", the intellisence can be arbitrary glitchy. Try to close the VS IDE delete all temporary directories (afaik there is at least `.vs` which is a hidden directory) and restart VS.

Comment: @dewaffled: I just made sure that this does not change anything. Regardless: Thanks for the reminder.